# Knockoutjs foreach custom bindinghandler with afterAdd

Tags: knockout.js, bindinghandlers

I would like to build a custom bindingHandler

ko.bindingHandlers.foreachWithHighlight that has an highlight effect when afterAdd.

[From documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)

```
yellowFadeIn: function(element, index, data) {
        $(element).filter("li")
                  .animate({ backgroundColor: 'yellow' }, 200)
                  .animate({ backgroundColor: 'white' }, 800);
    },
```

But I want to always add this to my valueAccessor and pass it to the foreach binding.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.foreachWithHighlight = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {
    return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context);
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {
    var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
    var newValue = function () {
        return {
            data: value,
            afterAdd: function(element, index, data) {
             $(element).filter("li")
              .animate({ backgroundColor: 'yellow' }, 200)
              .animate({ backgroundColor: 'white' }, 800);
            }
        };
    };
    return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, newValue, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context);
}};
```

How can I prevent it from running the first time when all the nodes from the server is added. I just want it to run when new nodes added.

Comment: do you initially populate your observableArray after it has been bound? (bind against empty observableArray and populate it when data comes back from an AJAX request, for example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your scenario correctly, then the issue is that the initial time that you populate your observableArray (after binding) you see your highlight. One way to handle a scenario like this would be to use `ko.utils.domData` or `$.data` to put a flag on the element to indicate that it is now ready for the highlight effect.

Something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.foreachWithHighlight = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {
        return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
            key = "forEachWithHightlight_initialized";

        var newValue = function () {
            return {
                data: value,
                afterAdd: function (el, index, data) {
                    if (ko.utils.domData.get(element, key)) {
                        $(el).filter("li")
                            .animate({
                            backgroundColor: 'yellow'
                        }, 200)
                            .animate({
                            backgroundColor: 'white'
                        }, 800);
                   }
                }
            };
        };

        ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, newValue, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context);

        //if we have not previously marked this as initialized and there are currently items in the array, then cache on the element that it has been initialized
        if (!ko.utils.domData.get(element, key) && value.length) {
            ko.utils.domData.set(element, key, true);
        }

        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/zGJX3/

Answer (score 0):

I've modified one of the knockout tutorials, it doesn't use a custom binding though but still drives the behaviour via `beforeRemove` and `afterAdd` which hook into the observableArray.

```
data-bind='template: { 
    foreach: planetsToShow,
    beforeRemove: hidePlanetElement,
    afterAdd: showPlanetElement 
}'
```

Depending on compatibility you could use css3 transitions as I've done here to give the newly added element a yellow colour that transitions to the normal one after a given timing.  (Although the timings and colourings I used need work ;))

In this fiddle it seems to be working by not applying to the original list, but I guess this might be down to at what stage the observableArray gets modified?

http://jsfiddle.net/8k8V5/1529/