# Manipulate with DOM elements on Knockoutjs "before-value-changed"

Tags: javascript, dom, animation, data-binding, knockout.js

Let's say, I just have a common Knockoutjs layout/approach:

```
    function User(data) {
        this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    }

    function UsersViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.users = ko.observableArray([]);
    }

    var viewModel = new UsersViewModel();
    service.initialize(viewModel);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

and HTML:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: users">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text:name"></span>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

What I want is **to apply some nice animation on the data changes** in Knockoutjs: **for existing DOM elements to disappear smoothly** (which would take some time while the animation of disappearing finishes), **and** right after that (or even right on starting of disappearing) **to start animation on new elements appearing**. (*In this very example -- for "li" elements to disappear separatly with every element separate animation (some delay between every element) (but that's not so important)*).

*(I consider here just will be a full replacement of elements (let's say not to be bothered much if new data contains items with the same id... that's complicated, I understand that)).*

As I understand, that might be pretty tough, and I should consider to change/extend Knockoutjs sources (right?) to deal with "***start-disappearing-animation***", "***disappearing-animation-finished***", "***start-appearing-animation***".

But is there at least any way **to prevent knockout to delete existent DOM elements** (*for me to handle that manually*)... some way to "detach" them from container.

Or, if nothing else above possible, then just to have "on before data changing" event?

Thank you!

Comment: Check out the docs on [custom bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) they have an example of an animated transition and you could probably extend that to whatever you need.

Comment: Hm... but that seems that "update" callback is rather for refreshing some element's state (in case, if in my example some `name` of some `user` data-object would change), but not allowing actually to call the animation after (and especially, before) some new elements appear/disappear (i.e., DOM object removed/created).

Comment: Either way, what you are looking for is a custom binding handler.

Comment: Could you be more specific? As I've just mentioned above, I can not see how is that possible to have something like 'on disposing/on removing' (in opposite to 'update' from the custom binding).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom binding to update the element.

You will then be able to do what you want before and after updating the element yourself.

Generic example:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.textAnimated = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();

        var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);

        // Before changing value
        // Do something

        $(element).text(valueUnwrapped);        

        // After changing value
        // Do something else
    } 
};
```

Example for a custom binding fading out the old value, then fading in the new value then printing done on the console:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.textAnimated = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();

        var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);

        $(element).fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $(element).text(valueUnwrapped);       

            $(element).fadeIn('slow', function() {
                console.log('done');
            });
        });
    } 
};
```

[See the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sq8NY/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am looking for another thing though. I need something rather not for the `title` to change (and indicate), but for the container `<ul data-bind="foreach: users">`. However, I can try something like this for it as well.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955314/knockoutjs-foreach-custom-bindinghandler-with-afteradd